# Raspberry Pi 3b+ black screen after start

Tags: boot, raspbian

My Raspberry Pi 3B+ hat the problem that VNC can't display the desktop. SO I connected it to a display and I had a black screen.

I can boot the system and can see the normal boot screen (Press "SHIFT" to Debug etc.) after that the screen is black again.

The red light glows and the green is flashing.

I can install another OS, see and have the normal desktop. After the updates the screen is black again?

Will Raspberry force me to buy the new Raspberry 4?

Answer (score 3):

I was successful adding a line like this to my `/boot/config.txt`:

```
# increase power for display
config_hdmi_boost=4
```

Please see [Video options in config.txt - Raspberry Pi Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md).
You need to reboot after that change.